RecyclerView showing old items briefly we visibility is changed from gone/invisible to visible
I'm unfortunately using the Views system with Paging 3 and I have an issue displaying the loading and empty state. Consider the following logic:
loadingView?.isVisible = refreshState is LoadState.Loading
recyclerView?.isVisible = refreshState is LoadState.NotLoading & itemCount > 0
emptyView?.isVisible = refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && itemCount < 1

This works fine, except for one annoying thing: when the visibility of the recycler view is changed from gone to visible (Loading -> NotLoading), the previous items of the list are shown for a brief moment, causing a "blink" effect.
I found two discussions about this

When I update Android RecyclerView with new items, old views are briefly shown before new views override them

Change in RecyclerView visibility from Gone to Visible, incorrectly shows previously removed item momentarily, before displaying newly added item


Those solutions did not work for, the view still shows the previous items for a moment.
I could solve this by just using Compose, but I don't want to migrate everything just because of this annoying bug.
Is there a way to solve this in the Views system? I also tried the LoadAdapter thing, but that is another joke in itself.
